# Azure AD B2C user - application assignment

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

I am trying to do application assignment to users in azure AD B2C. I have created few users and few applications through azure portal. I can see the list of applications from the 'Applications' side menu. However when I open any of the users from 'Users' side menu, and then navigate to the 'Applications'  tab, azure portal displays an empty white page. Is this an issue or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

[The application assignment to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-access-assignment-how-to-add-assignment) is an Azure AD (Enterprise) feature.

It is not supported by Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, if that is the case, what is the purpose of the 'Applications' tab that appears when an user is opened in the portal? Does that mean this feature is under construction in azure AD B2C? If not, is there a way i can achieve this functionality in azure AD B2C?

Comment: When you access the Azure AD blade for an Azure AD B2C directory, then it displays all of the Azure AD features (such as "Applications"), many of which aren't relevant for or supported by Azure AD B2C. What do you want to achieve with the application assignments?

Comment: When a user gets added to Azure AD B2C tenant (by signing up through a registered Application or via Graph API), he/she immediately gets the ability to log-in into any other registered application within the same B2C tenant. This is an undesirable behavior for us. We need an ability to restrict the users to be able to only log-in into the applications that they signed-up for and NOT the other ones. This is our requirement for your reference.

Comment: As Chris mentioned, this is not supported (please vote for the feature at aka.ms/aadb2cfeedback). The workaround is to use custom attributes. So each application would have it's own custom attribute for the user which indicates whether the user "signed up" or not for the application. Using custom policies, you can block the token from getting issued based on the value of that user attribute, or have the application reject the token if the custom attribute is not correct.

Comment: @Parakh I know this is an old question, but do you have any details on how to add a custom attribute to an Azure AD B2C user and make sure that the user cannot modify that attribute? This would mean it can't be part of a signup or edit profile user flow 

Once the custom attribute is returned as a claim it's easy to restrict access from the application - The user would be able to authenticate but wouldn't be authorised to access anything